# How to generate a call graph of a function with LLVM

Tags: llvm

The current -dot-callgraph pass will generate a call graph for the entire module, but I only want to generate a call graph of a function, which means the starting point is the specified function, and it contains all the functions that could be called from this function, directly and indirectly.

Comment: Did you figure this out?